# update query using hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to update a query using hibernate. My query is like this-

```
update premiummembership set user_wallet=:user_wallet + 50 where refferal_code=:refferal_code or shared_referral_code=:shared_referral_code
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THJcO.png)

In that table referral_code and shared_referral_code value is same but user_wallet value is different. I want that when database is updated value must be updated such as

```
first value shoule be updated to 200
second value should be updated to 50
```

How can I achieve this using hibernate?? Hope someone can help my problem.
Thanks in advance.